# How to Properly Use this in External Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two javascript functions that work fine so long as I keep them in the HTML of my head tag, but I'd like to move them to an external javascript file.

```
function uploadImageSB() {

    Shadowbox.init({});

    // shadowbox for image upload
    Shadowbox.open({

        content: 'photo.cgi?function=photo_upload',
        player: 'iframe',
        title: 'Image Upload',
        height: 200,
        width: 500,
        options: {

            onFinish: function () {

                // get the iframe
                var iframe = document.getElementById('sb-player');

                var formName = 'photoForm';

                // add an event listener to determine when the sb form is fully loaded
                if (iframe.addEventListener) {
                    // use addEventListener for Safari, Chrome, Firefox
                    iframe.addEventListener("load", getTA(formName), true);
                } else {
                    // use attachEvent for IE
                    iframe.attachEvent("onload", getTA(formName));
                }
            }
        }
    })
};
```

The above javascript calls this next function:

```
function getTA(fn) {

    // get the contents of the tinymce editor
    var ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
    var content = ed.save();

    // dynamically create textarea
    var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
    ta.textContent = content;
    ta.name = 'article';
    ta.value = ta.textContent;

    // get the iframe content
    var iframeContent = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;

    // append the textarea to the shadowbox form, but do not display it
    var form = iframeContent.getElementById(fn);
    form.appendChild(ta);
    form.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].style.display = 'none';
};
```

I think the problem is with my usage of `this` here:

```
var iframeContent = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
```

But I'm not sure how fix it. thanks.

Comment: So whats the question? Have you put it in a external file and it doesn't work or you want to know how to put it into an external file?

Comment: When I put it in an external file, it no longer works. I suspect its because I'm using the line of code I shared incorrectly (though I don't know this for sure). Yes, I'd like to know what I need to change to get it to work in an external file.

Comment: Putting JavaScript in an external JS-file shouldn't make any difference as long as you reference the JS-file properly. The only thing I can think of in that case is that you reference the external file prior to Shadowbox, thus `Shadowbox` will be undefined when you call it. Do you get any JS errors?

Comment: Yes, I do get a javascript error. Firefox reports that this.contentWindow is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding your code shouldn't work when you are calling from head too. Problem is with your following code.

```
            if (iframe.addEventListener) {
                // use addEventListener for Safari, Chrome, Firefox
                iframe.addEventListener("load", getTA(formName), true);
            } else {
                // use attachEvent for IE
                iframe.attachEvent("onload", getTA(formName));
            }
```

You are calling the getTA(formName) function there itself and because it is called in the context of window, you dont get the iframe as your context ie this.

To solve this problem you need to provide it as a listener as a function object as argument as given below.
EDIT :  Using closure to support using same fn for multiple instance.

```
                if (iframe.addEventListener) {
                    // use addEventListener for Safari, Chrome, Firefox
                    iframe.addEventListener("load", (function(){
                         return function(){
                              getTa.call(this, formName);
                         }
                    })(), true);
                } else {
                    // use attachEvent for IE
                    iframe.attachEvent("onload", (function(){
                         return function(){
                              getTa.call(this, formName);
                         }
                    })());
                }
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the code I've been using - and it works great. However, I need to pass getTA two different formName's because I need to use this same function more than once (the only difference is that the forms each have a unique id (photoForm & viewForm). As soon as I try to pass one of these id's I get an error (this.contentWindow is undefined). I guess I could write two distinct functions, but I don't understand why I can't use the same one?

Comment: Updated my answer, that should do it.